# "throw" crashes program, but compiles fine

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction

My program compiles fine, but crashes everytime throw (not inside of a try...catch block) is called.

Here are the command like arguments used for all files in the project:

`mingw32-g++.exe -fexceptions -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -D_MBCS -DNO_SOCKLEN_T -DDONTUSEMEMMANAGER  -Wall -g -W -fexceptions -DDEBUG`

(I know that Wall makes W unnecessary and that I have -fexceptions in there twice.)

edit: I know that the there's actually nothing wrong with that behaviour. the thing is, it used to work aka the program wouldn't crash. but some days ago I made a change to some of the files , compiled again and all of a sudden it crashed

Comment: So you're asking why an un-caught exception stops the run?

Comment: Urgh no ofc not. The thing is, it used not to used crash, but some days ago I made a code change, compiled the program and all of a sudden it would crash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is the expected behavior. The standard says [except.handle]:

> If no matching handler is found, the function std::terminate() is called; [...]

Comment: Yeah, but how can I change that?

Comment: @NiklasKarbaum: Join the ISO WG21 and persuade them to change the rules... Seriously: perhaps either remove the `throw` or add a `try`? Also without some code people on SO won't be able to help you much.

Comment: It's not my code, but I guess I'll ask the project admin to remove the throw. thanks for everything

Comment: @NiklasKarbaum it is likely throwing for a reason, so simply removing the throw is unlikely to be a good solution. You should try catching the exception.

Answer (score 4):

That is called an unhandled exception. The expected behavior is that the program should exit.